# startForeground fails with Bad notification for startForeground

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I'm trying to start foreground service but it fails

```kotlin
val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
     val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
     val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder
     builder =
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
             val channelId = "noti_channel"
             val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "Notification Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
             if (!getSharedPreferences("Imhere", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isNotificationCreated", false)) {
                 (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel)
                 getSharedPreferences("Imhere", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isNotificationCreated", true).apply()
             }
             NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
         } else {
             NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         }
     builder
         .setContentTitle("Location Service")
         .setContentText("Service running in foreground")
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
     startForeground(502, builder.build())
```

This code is in Service itself, so Service onCreate method calls this code block
It worked last time, but when I removed the app and reinstalled it, then It started to fail.

```
2020-08-30 05:08:19.233 706-706/{app package name} E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: {app package name}, PID: 706
        android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2141)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried adding an icon to the notification?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I tried with `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable)` but It doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer:
It was because of backup content.
In my code, I used SharedPreference to check if the notification channel was created. But `BackupManager` saved my SharedPreference even after app was removed, so when the app is reinstalled, notification channel is not created.
I changed `AndroidManifest.xml` as shown below and it cleared my SharedPreference. Now it works very well.

```xml
<application
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupOnly="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```