# Bad notification for startForeground Android 11 & 10

Tags: java, android, notifications

Got the error only in android 11 and 10, other's are good, already check this other question seems ok with my code any idea guys

[startForeground fails with Bad notification for startForeground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651433/startforeground-fails-with-bad-notification-for-startforeground)

[android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529974/android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-for-startforeground)

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 1);

        Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

        Intent firstActivityIntent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(FirstActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(firstActivityIntent);

        Intent notificationUpdateIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateNotificationActivity.class);
        notificationUpdateIntent.putExtra("ID", id);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationUpdateIntent);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(id, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noteappicon)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
```

ERROR i got in Android 11

```
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2005)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

and this is the error in 10

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=channel1 pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x50 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1945)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground
Added to post

Comment: thats all i have in log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529974/android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-for-startforeground)

Answer (score 10):

My mistake for Channel ID need to create some Channel id just like my past question

I created another class for Channel id

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_1_ID,
                "Channel 1",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        channel1.setDescription("This is channel 1");

        NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_2_ID,
                "Channel 2",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );
        channel2.setDescription("This is channel 2");

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
    }
}
```